# Angular 5 - Detect changes when using websockets

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, ngzone, angular-changedetection

I have a problem working with websockets and displaying the changes in real-time.
I have an array of **orders**. This array is coming from a **NodeJS** backend server from calling on `ngOnInit()` method my `orderService.getOrders()` which fetches the orders from the backend through a REST call.
After this the orders are rendered into the template with the correct information.

I'm also using websockets to handle two type of events: `placeOrder` (when a new order is submitted to the backed through POST) and `updateOrder` (when an existing order is changed).

Here is a relevant part of that code:

```
  webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
      const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
      if (message === 'PlaceOrderEvent') {
        self.handlePlaceOrderEvent(message);
      } else if (message === 'UpdateOrderStatusEvent') {
        self.handleUpdateOrderEvent(message);
      }
    };
```

This is working correctly and I can see the modified data inside those two methods if I `console.log()` but the problem is that the changes are not reflected into the template only after I refresh the page.

I already tried using **ChangeDetectorRef** and calling `detectChanges()` and the end of the `handle()` methods but with no success.

How can this be achieved and display a new order in real-time into my template or display the changes to an existing one without refreshing the page?

EDIT: more relevant parts of the code

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  orders: Order[];

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrders();
    this.openWebSocket();
  }

    self.orderService.getOrders().subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data.error) {
          console.error(data.error);
        } else {
          if (Array.isArray(data)) {
            self.orders = data.map(function (o) {
            ...
            //parsing the data from the backend
    }

    openWebSocket() {
    ...
    //onmessage
      webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
          const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
          if (message === 'PlaceOrderEvent') {
            self.handlePlaceOrderEvent(message);
          } else if (message === 'UpdateOrderStatusEvent') {
            self.handleUpdateOrderEvent(message);
          }
        };
    }

    handlePlaceOrderEvent(order) {
    const self = this;
    self.orders.unshift({
      ...
      //parsing the new order coming from websocket message
      status: self.statuses[0],
      placed: Date.now()
    });
   //<===== here I tried putting changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide us a small repro of your scenario?

Comment: Check my edit, I posted more relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Have you tried to run your code in `ngZone.run`?

Comment: I tried placing what it's inside the handle methods in `ngZone.run` but It didn't help. Did I placed it wrong?

Comment: did you tried Observable and subject ??

Comment: Can you give me an example?